# How can I add the ratio on the bars in a stacked bar

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I would like to add the ratio between the value counts of a stacked bar plot above the bars, how can I do it?
here is the example data frame:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " TargetVar  Var1    Var2       Var3
 0        0        0         7
 0        0        1         1
 0        1        0         3
 0        1        1         7
 1        0        0         5
 1        0        1         1
 1        1        0         0
 1        1        1         6
 0        0        0         8
 0        0        1         5
 1        1        1         4
 0        0        1         2
 1        0        0         9
 1        1        1         2  ", header = TRUE)
```

I wrote the following code:

```
counts <- table(dat$TargetVar, dat$Var3)
barplot(counts, main="Is churn",
        xlab="Var1", col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts))
```

and got this chart, but how can I add the ratio above the bars?

[image: bar chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
barX <- barplot(counts, main="Is churn",
        xlab="Var1", col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts))

ratios <- apply(counts, 2, paste, collapse = "/")
text(cex=.9, x=barX, y=apply(counts, 2, sum) + .05, ratios, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

**EDIT** Per your request:

```
ratios <- paste(apply(counts, 2, paste, collapse = "/"), " = ",
    apply(counts, 2, function(x) x[1]/x[2]), "%")
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler, can I make the text look like this : 3/5 = 0.6%  ?